# Filter data by minutes in SAS (PROC SQL) - Using time in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, time, sas, where-clause, proc-sql

Trying to pull up all records where a phone call was answered in less than 1 minute.

My data set, p1, looks a bit like this

```
Call_date  pick_up
05/30/2018 0:19
05/29/2018 1:45
05/29/2018 0:37
05/28/2018 1:01
```

This is within SAS. When I run a PROC CONTENTS, the informat I get for the pick_up column is TIME20.3

So I try to run this code:

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT p1.call_date,p1.pick_up
FROM p1

WHERE p1.pick_up < 1:00time20.3;

QUIT;
```

And I get the following errors:

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, !, !!, &, *, **, +, -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, AND, EQ, EQT, EXCEPT, 
           GE, GET, GROUP, GT, GTT, HAVING, INTERSECT, LE, LET, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, OR, ORDER, OUTER, UNION, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, 
           ~=.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Is there a simple way to filter my data by minutes and seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS stores times in seconds, so you can do the following.

```
WHERE p1.pick_up < 60;
```

You can also specify a time literal as follows:

```
WHERE p1.pick_up < '01:00't;
```

A format controls the appearance of a variable, but does not change the underlying variable.

You can find a tutorial on SAS date and times here: 
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Working-with-Dates-and-Times-in-SAS-Tutorial/ta-p/424354

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! And thanks for the link as well, will definitely take a look. This is somewhat relevant...if I wanted to retrieve records between 10pm and 1am for example, would it be safe to assume that***** time>='22:00't AND time <='01:00't******   would work?

Comment: No on the question on between 10pm and 1am.  Time is measured in seconds from midnight.  So 1am is 3600 (60*60*1) and 10pm is 79,200 (60*60*22),  so `time >=79200 AND time <= 3600` will never be true.  You need an `OR`, not an `AND`

Comment: For that question you need to consider dates as well as time. Because you're likely thinking of 10PM to 1AM as a continuous time period that crosses days, not midnight to 1 am and 10pm to 12am.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I had never encountered a data set with hours/minutes before so that had confused me. Understanding that SAS measures time in seconds from midnight was essentially the knowledge-gap in that instance. Thanks again!